# typeperf logging to SQL

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I am trying to log typeperf to an ACCESS database and am not having any luck.  I created an access database, added the File DSN, and when I try to run the command:

typeperf -si 15 -f SQL "\Process(*)\ID Process" -o SQL:accessDSN!log

the output just says Unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
TYPEPERF -f SQL "\Process(*)\ID Process" -si 15 -o SQL:accessDSN!log
```

Comment: yes that is the same command just different order of arguments, but trying that yeilds the same result.

Comment: I thought maybe the order had something to do with it. I tried the same setup you're describing and wasn't able to reproduce your result. My error was Call to SQLExecDirect failed with (Null). MS has a hotfix for the error, but apparently that has been rolled into a service pack already.